# VSCode look for Go packages in different directory

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, grpc, bazel

I successfully used rules_go to build a gRPC service:

```
go_proto_library(
    name = "processor_go_proto",
    compilers = ["@io_bazel_rules_go//proto:go_grpc"],
    importpath = "/path/to/proto/package",
    proto = ":processor_proto",
    deps = ["//services/shared/proto/common:common_go_proto"],
)
```

However, I'm not sure how to import the resulting file in VSCode. The generated file is nested under `bazel_bin` and under the original proto file path; so to import this, it seems like I would need to write out the entire path (including the `bazel_bin` part) to the generated Go file. To my understanding, there doesn't seem to be a way to instruct VSCode to look under certain folders that only contain Go packages/files; [everything seems to need a `go.mod`](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md) file. This makes it quite difficult to develop in.

For clarity, my directory structure looks something like this:

```
WORKSPACE
bazel-bin
  - path
     - to
        - generated_Go_file.go
go.mod
go.sum
proto
  - path
     - to
        - gRPC_proto.proto
main.go
```

`main.go` should use the `generated_Go_file.go`.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't use bazel, but heard a special gopackagesdriver is necessary to make vscode-go (gopls) and bazel to work. https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/wiki/Editor-setup#visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Bazel and so cannot help with the Bazel configuration. It's likely there is a way to specify the generated code location so that you can revise this to reflect you preference.

The outline you provide of the generated code, is workable though and a common pattern. Often the generated proto|gRPC code is placed in a module's `gen` subdirectory.

This is somewhat similar to vendoring where your code incorporates what may often be a 3rd-party's stubs (client|server) into your code. The stubs must reflect the proto(s) package(s) and, when these are 3rd-party, using `gen` or `bazel-bin` provide a way to keep potentially multiple namespaces discrete.

You're correct that the import for `main.go`, could (!) be prefixed with the module name from `go.mod` (first line) followed by the folder path to the generated code. This **is** standard go packaging and treats the generated code in a similar way to vendored modules.

Another approach is to use|place the generated code in a different module.

For code generated from 3rd-party protos, this may be preferable and the generated code may be provided by the 3rd-party in a module that you can `go get` or add to your `go.mod`.

An example of this approach is Google [Well-Known Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf). The proto (sources) are bundled with `protoc` (`lib` directory) and, when `protoc` compiles sources that references any of these, the Go code that is generated includes imports that reference a Google-hosted location of the generated code (!) for these types (`google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known`).

Alternatively, you can replicate this behavior without having to use an external repo. The `bazel-bin` folder must be outside of the current module. Each distinct module in `bazel-bin`, would need its own `go.mod` file. You would include in a `require` block in your code's `go.mod` file references to the modules' (one or more) locations. You don't need to publish the module to a external repo but can simply `require ( name => path/to/module )` to provide a local reference.